# sparksql Convert dataframe to json

Tags: json, apache-spark

My requirement is to pass dataframe as input parameter to a scala class which saves the data in json format to hdfs.

The input parameter looks like this:

```
case class ReportA(
                  parm1: String,
                  parm2: String,
                  parm3: Double,
                  parm4: Double,
                  parm5: DataFrame
                  )
```

I have created a JSON object for this parameter like:

```
def write(xx: ReportA) = JsObject(
      "field1" -> JsString(xx.parm1),
      "field2" -> JsString(xx.parm2),
      "field3" -> JsNumber(xx.parm3),
      "field4" -> JsNumber(xx.parm4),
      "field5" -> JsArray(xx.parm5)
    )
```

parm5 is a dataframe and wanted to convert as Json array.

How can I convert the dataframe to Json array?

Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: have you see toJson method from the below https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DataFrame can be seen to be the equivalent of a plain-old table in a database, with rows and columns. You can't just get a simple array from it, the closest you woud come to an array would be with the following structure :

```
[
    "col1": [val1, val2, ..], 
    "col2": [val3, val4, ..],
    "col3": [val5, val6, ..]
]
```

To achieve a similar structure, you could use the `toJSON` method of the DataFrame API to get an `RDD<String>` and then do `collect` on it (be careful of any `OutOfMemory` exceptions).

You now have an `Array[String]`, which you can simply transform in a `JsonArray` depending on the JSON library you are using.

Beware though, this seems like a really bizarre way to use Spark, you generally don't output and transform an RDD or a DataFrame directly into one of your objects, you usually spill it out onto a storage solution.

Comment: Note: I think the method is named `toJSON` (with JSON in all caps).

Comment: @JoshRosen Indeed, I've update my answer, thanks for pointing that out !